# SpriteKit Scene constraints

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can I add the constraints to the nodes in SpriteKitScene?

I want to include sprite nodes that are resized according to the device's display size.

Comment: What is your programming question? Please add code!!!

Comment: My question si How can I implement the constraints in SpriteKit Scene! The code is not necessary.

Comment: you don't do constraints in SpriteKit,  the `scaleMode` determines how games will look.  Use `AspectFill` to have it be the same size on all devices

Comment: How can I use Aspect fill ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use view width and height to proportionally increase size of nodes!

Comment: I want to create game whose nodes are the same size for iPhone SE, for iPhone 8 and plus for iPad!

Comment: if I remove the question I have to wait 2 days to make another, please reply to me?